# Jquery replace not working

Tags: jquery, replace

Hi I am trying to change the contents of a hidden input.

```
var temp = $("#header").val().replace("(/<\/div><div>/g","<br>");
```

I tried using the following replace but it does not change it.

May I know what I did wrong? I am trying to replace:

```
</div><div>
```

to

```
<br>
```

**EDIT - this is my program flow**

- User enters input to a wysiwyg text editor which produces the  output
- Save the user input to database
- Go to another page where the wysiwyg input is retrieved from database and save it to input type hidden
- Replace the `</div><div>` to a `<br>` which is then outputted to a div

Comment: What do you do with the  `temp` variable after setting it?

Comment: I want to output it to a pdf using jspdf, but it does not understand HTML codes, and I am planning to output the line separately after a split.

Comment: what is an example of the contents you are trying to modify? and what is the expected result?  You want to keep the first opening div and the last closing div?

Comment: So you are currently logging `temp` to the console or something and that's how you know the replace isn't working? Or...?

Comment: I use alert to see the replaced content of temp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k9pxe3qg/

Comment: Though you really shouldn't [parse html with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all ocurrences in a string, the correct syntax with regExp is:

```
var temp = $("#header").val().replace(/<\/div><div>/g,"<br>");
```

You can test it, here:

```
'</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div>'.replace(/<\/div><div>/g,"<br>");
```

returns:

```
<br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this only replaces the first occurence of `</div><div>`, you'll have to use Gaurang Tandon's solution to replace them all.

Comment: Yes as Drown said, it only replaces the first occurence, and I need to replace all

Comment: Thank you Javier! I suppose it didn't work because I put a " on the Regexp

Comment: you are welcome :), as you see if you quoted the regExp y treated as normal string

Comment: $(function(){
var text="132|233|424";
var temp = text.replace("|",",");
    alert(temp);
});

expected result is  132,233,424 but its returning 132,233|424

Comment: You need a regExp to replace all occurrences, based on w3c documentation:
Note: If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier (see "More Examples" below).
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
.replace(/<\/div><div>/g,"<br>");
```

The RegExp should not be enclosed within quotes else it would be a String. Also, the `.val()` method is used for textareas. Use `.html()` for `header`, `div`s, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry I was using input type hidden not textarea, I wrote wrong. However after I change to your code, it still does not work